# How to run full ahk file from C# using autohotkey.interop

Tags: c#, autohotkey

I use autohotkey to do the work. In the background, however, anti-cheat software detects autohotkey. So I found a way to use AHK with C#: [Autohotkey.interop](https://github.com/amazing-andrew/AutoHotkey.Interop).

But I cannot find a way to run the autohotkey full source using Autohotkey.interop.

like this

```
AutoHotkeyEngine ahk = AutoHotkeyEngine.Instance;
ahk.LoadScript("test.ahk");
```

test.ahk

```
F1::

    CoordMode,ToolTip,Screen

    MouseGetPos,xpos, ypos
    MsgBox, %xpos% , %ypos%

F2::

    ExitApp
```

I want to compile the normal .ahk file into C#.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer to your question, but if anti-cheat-detection is a problem, you might try running the compiled AHK-file from within a [sandbox](https://www.sandboxie.com). I've been told this does the trick.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But the Anti-Cheat program is also detecting "Sandiebox".

Do you have any other "Sandbox" programs you know?

Comment: @MinSuO woah what a stubborn cheat-detection. No, I don't know any. Maybe Google does. Have you tried compiling your script to an exe and running it? (thus, no "AutoHotkey.exe" process will be created anymore). Cant really think of any other ways, but I am sure there are common practices to prevent anti-ceat-detection-engines from detecting

Comment: @Blauhim I'm sorry for the rudimentary question. And very, very grateful.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a mistake in what I said yesterday.

The Anti Cheat program does not detect "SandieBox"

  It was "AutoHotkey.ahk" and "AutoHotkey.exe" executed in it.

I do not understand how an anti-cheat program can access a process running in the Sandboxie program.

The name of the anti-cheat program is "Xigncode3" and "NGS (Nexon Game Security)"

I think "NGS" is detecting Autohotkey in Sandieboxie.


Do you have a strategy for this problem?

Comment: yes so what happens if you compile your script into a file called, for examplle, myScript.exe ? -> thus, no more "AutoHotkey.exe" detection